# How can i move a cylinder right and left?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Between two points or only to the left nonestop or only to the right nonestop.

In this code i spin the cylinder but i can't move it to the sides:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MakeTwoPoints3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 10f;

    public float delta = 15.5f;  // Amount to move left and right from the start point
    public float moveSpeed = 5.0f;
    private Vector3 startPos;

    void Start()
    {
        startPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        transform.position += transform.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
    }
}
```

If i make transform.right it will move the cylinder in circle on place up and down in circle. If i make transform.up it will move it to me i mean like forward but to the camera but at least it will move it. And if i make transform.Forward again it will make circles and will remove the cylinder in circles up down.

I can't figure out how to move it to the sides.

Comment: What value does `transform.right` have?

Answer (score 2):

You need use `Vector3.right` instead of `transform.right`.

```
void Update()
{
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.position += Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed;
}
```

When you use `transform.right`, the Vector3 will adopt the local rotations of that object's transform. Meaning, if the object was rotated 45 degrees around the Y axis, your `transform.right` vector would be on an angle. If you keep translating an object along it's local axis while you rotate it, it will travel in a circle.

On the other hand, `Vector3.right` is always in world space so it will always face "true" right.

Comment: I tried your solution the cylinder is not moving to the right or left it's moving a bit to the left but also to the camera to me. I mean it's like moving to the left and backward together. I recorded a very short video clip showing it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7pFY8rDK7Rg&feature=youtu.be

Comment: That's because your camera is rotated. Neither `transform.right` nor `vector3.right` is going to translate the object to the right relative to the camera.